# Why am I seeing erratic behavior by a variable stored in "information memory" on MSP430?

Tags: msp430, non-volatile-memory

Sometimes a variable in information memory updates as expected and sometimes not.

For example, I would expect the following program to print...

```
0
0
1
```

...but, in fact, it prints...

```
0
1
1
```

```
int __attribute__(( __section__(".infoA") )) persistent_data;


void unlock_persistant_data() {
    SYSCFG0 = PFWP;                     // Write protect only program FRAM. Interestingly it appears that the password is not needed here?
}

void lock_persistant_data() {
    SYSCFG0 = PFWP | DFWP;              // Write protect both program and data FRAM.
}

void main() {

    unlock_persistant_data();
    persistent_data=0;
    lock_persistant_data();
    print( persistent_data );

    persistent_data++;
    print( persistent_data );

    unlock_persistant_data();
    persistent_data++;
    lock_persistant_data();
    print( persistent_data );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the variable `persistent_data` is put into non-volatile memory by the `section` attribute, the compiler still treats it as a normal (ram-based) variable so it can optimize away some accesses. In this case, it used the copy that was in a register rather than loading the value from the FRAM.

This can be fixed by marking the variable in FRAM as `volatile`, which makes the compiler access the memory location every time it is used.

```
volatile int __attribute__(( __section__(".infoA") )) persistent_data;
```